# request_irq returns EBUSY and free_irq says that the IRQ is free

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, interrupt-handling

I am developing a driver for the IRQ number 8, which corresponds to the RTC Clock. I have the following problem. When I request that IRQ with request_irq I get an EBUSY error. I thought that using free_irq(8,NULL) first should solve the problem (at least it worked with kernel version 2.6.24-23-generic). However, when I use it, I get the error "Trying to free already-free IRQ 8". Checking /proc/interrupts I see the following:

`8:          1          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0`

This is the error I get in dmesg:

```
[14876.256173] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[14876.256182] WARNING: at kernel/irq/manage.c:1195 __free_irq+0x91/0x190()
[14876.256185] Hardware name: Aspire 7720     
[14876.256187] Trying to free already-free IRQ 8
[14876.256189] Modules linked in: cmos_driver_alarm(O+) cmos_driver_ioctl(O) nls_cp437 vfat fat usb_storage uas listapci_driver(O) cmos_driver_read(O) aes_i586 cryptd aes_generic fuse mxl5005s zl10353 dvb_usb_ce6230 dvb_usb dvb_core arc4 joydev nouveau iwl3945 iwlegacy mac80211 ir_lirc_codec lirc_dev drm_kms_helper snd_hda_codec_realtek ir_mce_kbd_decoder ttm ir_sanyo_decoder firewire_ohci sdhci_pci sdhci cfg80211 drm ir_sony_decoder ir_jvc_decoder snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_pcm mmc_core tg3 intel_agp intel_gtt agpgart r852 sm_common nand nand_ecc ir_rc6_decoder iTCO_wdt firewire_core snd_page_alloc i2c_i801 r592 snd_hwdep serio_raw nand_ids ir_rc5_decoder libphy iTCO_vendor_support crc_itu_t i2c_core mtd memstick psmouse rc_rc6_mce ir_nec_decoder thermal battery pcspkr processor video button ac acer_wmi mxm_wmi evdev sparse_keymap rfkill ene_ir wmi rc_core vboxnetflt(O) vboxdrv(O) vhba(O) snd_seq snd_timer snd_seq_device snd soundcore ext4 crc16 jbd2 mbcache sr_mod cdrom sd_mod pata_acpi hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid ata_generic ata_piix libata scsi_mod uhci_hcd ehci_hcd usbcore usb_common [last unloaded: cmos_driver_alarm]
[14876.256283] Pid: 10363, comm: insmod Tainted: G        W  O 3.3.1-1-ARCH #1
[14876.256286] Call Trace:
[14876.256292]  [<c01351f2>] warn_slowpath_common+0x72/0xa0
[14876.256296]  [<c01a89e1>] ? __free_irq+0x91/0x190
[14876.256299]  [<c01a89e1>] ? __free_irq+0x91/0x190
[14876.256303]  [<c01352c3>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x33/0x40
[14876.256306]  [<c01a89e1>] __free_irq+0x91/0x190
[14876.256310]  [<c01a8b23>] free_irq+0x43/0xa0
[14876.256314]  [<f803501e>] init_driver+0x1e/0xc8 [cmos_driver_alarm]
[14876.256318]  [<c0101124>] do_one_initcall+0x34/0x170
[14876.256325]  [<f8035000>] ? 0xf8034fff
[14876.256330]  [<c018f295>] sys_init_module+0x8c5/0x1a70
[14876.256342]  [<c04ae85f>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
[14876.256345] ---[ end trace 81112f980bdc845e ]---
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Thing is you're passing `NULL` as the argument to `free_irq`. That function checks it to match the `request_irq` before allowing you to free it.

Just look at the function [`_free_irq`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/manage.c#L1173):

```
/* desc is obtained via irq_to_desc */
action_ptr = &desc->action;
for (;;) {
        action = *action_ptr;

        if (!action) {
                WARN(1, "Trying to free already-free IRQ %d\n", irq);
                raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore(&desc->lock, flags);

                return NULL;
        }

        /* If dev_id doesn't match it just goes on. */
        if (action->dev_id == dev_id)
                break;

        action_ptr = &action->next;
}
```

Comment: How can I do to completely free a specific IRQ? How can I get the dev_id?

Comment: @JavierJ.SalmeronGarcia The best way would be to get the rtc to free it.

Comment: How can I do that? Is there any API for the RTC?

Comment: @JavierJ.SalmeronGarcia Don't know. Look for the paths that call `free_irq`.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the author has been nice enough to request the IRQ line with the flag `IRQF_SHARED` set. Calling `request_irq` with `IRQF_SHARED`, should allow your module to share the IRQ line with the RTC module in that case.